# Getting Android app to run on more devices?

Tags: android

This is a beginner question, but what are the steps needed to get my app to run on more devices? I noticed that my new update (on beta) is running on fewer devices. Do I just need to update the targetminsdk version in build gradle or is there anything else I need to do? I think I should be aiming for minsdkversion 18?

My versions in gradle are here

```
compileSdkVersion 23

    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why is the min not lower?

Comment: Yeah, you can change `minSdkVersion` to be 18, but prepare to resolve any issues that arise if you are using APIs that require 21

Comment: What's the recommended configuration? It's a super simple app (one activity, with a few buttons and sounds. It also uses the camera and google analytics. 
minSdkVersion:15?

Answer (score 0):

**Min sdk version** : Is the earliest release of the Android SDK that your application can run on. So this is what you want to change if you want more devices supported for your app.

**Target sdk version** : The version your application was targeted to run on. Ideally this is because of some sort of optimal run conditions.

Android Developers forum says :

> The dashboard for Platform Versions is updated regularly to show the distribution of active devices running each version of Android, based
>   on the number of devices that visit the Google Play Store. Generally,
>   it’s a good practice to support about 90% of the active devices, while
>   targeting your app to the latest version.

For more details, go through : [Supporting Different Platform Versions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html)

For **API 18** : your app will run on approximately **76.9%** of the devices that are active on Google Play Store.

For **API 21** : your app will run on approximately **40.5%** of the devices that are active on Google Play Store.

Now that is a huge difference, that you may not really want for your app. So you need to weigh your pros and cons of having **Latest API support** to **getting more users**. I would infact recommend you to go for API 18 instead of 21, unless you have some very important functionality that necessitates API 21 and above and can't be done without.